# how to index the last 2 dim of a tensor by another tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor A with shape [2,3, 55,45], and I have another index tensor B with shape [2,2]. I want to use tensor B's last dim as the index of the last two dim of tensor A to create the conresponding tensor C with shape [2,3,1,1], A and B 's first dim represent the batch_size, how should I do in pytorch?

```
A = torch.randn(2, 3, 55, 45)
B = torch.LongTensor([[2, 5], [10, 20]])

C = A.index_select(2,index = B[:,0]).index_select(3,index = B[:,1])
```

i try to solve it, but i failed

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use `torch.cat` combined with tensor slicing.

```
C = torch.cat((A[0, :, B[0, 0], B[0, 1]], A[1, :, B[1, 0], B[1, 1]]), dim=0)
```

`A[0, :, B[0, 0], B[0, 1]]` means "for tensor `A` at index 0, take all second dim, take value in the third dim that has index `B[0, 0]`, and take value in the fourth dim that has index `B[0, 1]`". Repeat the same with `A[1,...]`.

It is hard to determine if this is correct, so it would be very helpful if you can also post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).